# [Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]] . This error is occuring On mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My sample code is here.  I am learning from book developing_backbone.js_applications 
I have installed mongodb on my PC. I searched for it on this site with answers but no clue.
has anyone got any solutions? Thanks!

```
// Module dependencies.
var application_root = __dirname,
    express = require('express'), //Web framework
    path = require('path'), //Utilities for dealing with file paths
    mongoose = require('mongoose'); //MongoDB integration
//Create server
var app = express();
// Configure server
app.configure(function () {
    //parses request body and populates request.body
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    //checks request.body for HTTP method overrides
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    //perform route lookup based on URL and HTTP method
    app.use(app.router);
    //Where to serve static content
    app.use(express.static(path.join(application_root, 'site')));
    //Show all errors in development
    app.use(express.errorHandler({
        dumpExceptions: true,
        showStack: true
    }));
});


//Start server
var port =4711;
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port %d in %s mode',
        port, app.settings.env);
});

// Routes
app.get( '/api', function( request, response ) {

    response.send( 'Library API is running and the requestis' );
});

//Connect to database
mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://localhost/library_database', function(err) { if (err) console.log(err); } );
//Schemas
var Book = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String,
    releaseDate: Date
});
//Models
var BookModel = mongoose.model( 'Book', Book );

//Get a list of all books
app.get( '/api/books', function( request, response ) {
    return BookModel.find( function( err, books ) {
        if( !err ) {
            return response.send( books );
        } else {
            return console.log( err );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this windows or linux?

Comment: PC? Windows Linux or Mac? and how are you running it?

Comment: Windows 8 Operation system

Comment: Running as a service? Or did you just install it? If you did not install as a service and start that then you need to be running in a command line window. [Manual Page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/).

Comment: I am runing it in a command line window with a command "node server.js" in the directory where server.js file shown above present

Comment: That's your node application. You run the `mongod` server separately. Your app does not start this up. Read the manual page link I gave you as it will show you what to do.

Comment: thanks bro that's a lot of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have mongodb installed and running locally?? 
Leave a terminal tab or window open with mongo running there.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using a local Database on your machine, you have to execute mongod (which could be found inside bin folder of downloaded and unzipped mongodb).